# Same access for the Org when it has 2 domains and 2 mail ids

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory

We have a scenario like this:
We got 2 domains from GCP and one primary and another one is new sub-domain and all the users were created in Azure AD.
I would like to how users will be synced with when both domains have same users and need access to multiple apps.
2 domains same users but need single access to different apps and users are created in Azure AD.

2 domains same users but need single access to different apps and users are created in Azure AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Workforce Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workforce-identity-federation):

> Workforce identity federation lets you use an external identity
> provider (IdP) to authenticate and authorize a workforce—a group of
> users, such as employees, partners, and contractors—using IAM, so that
> the users can access Google Cloud services.

To configure [Workforce Identity Federation with Azure Identity Provider](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workforce-sign-in-azure-ad) check here.

Comment: Ok thank you. Will try from my end and get back tou you.

Comment: To be more clear how to setup SSO between 2 GCP cloud identities; I.e service provider and identity provider. Is possible?

Comment: WIF supports OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol, so any identity provider which supports OIDC can be configured. I am using Workload Identity Federation for workload which are running on external cloud and on-premise, not tried workforce identity. Another thought, if you have multiple identities, check for sync/add multiple domains to primary domain. Check https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-multiple-orgs. Accept the answer, if satisfies your requirement. Thanks!